# Why did the dependencies override not work as expect in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to force my project to use `hooks_riverpod` version `1.0.0-dev.6`, so I specify the dependency in pubspect.yaml like this:

```
dependencies:
  hooks_riverpod: 1.0.0-dev.6
dependency_overrides:
  hooks_riverpod: 1.0.0-dev.6
```

but when I compile the project, the dependencies still using another version `1.0.0-dev.10`:

```
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/riverpod-1.0.0-dev.10/lib/src/async_value_converters.dart:223:39: Error: The method 'ignore' isn't defined for the class 'Future<State>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ignore'.
            loadingCompleter!.future..ignore(),
```

am I missing something? what should I do to force the flutter dependencies using version `1.0.0-dev.6`? BTW, I already running `flutter update/upgrade/outdate` for many times. I also tried to delete pub-cache folder and redownload the dependencies package. I found the .packages file always auto generate this line :

```
riverpod:file:///Users/dolphin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/riverpod-1.0.0-dev.10/lib/
```

this is my flutter version info:

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter doctor                                                                                                         ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is connected. (code -13)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
(base)
```